# reactjs project working fine on local...but not working after deployment...any suggestion?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my first reactjs app. (It's a quiz app) In local the app is working fine.. after deploy is not working as expected. [Here](https://francescocori.github.io/francesco-quizApp/) you can find the deploy version and a soon you start to play answering the first question you will notice the problem that the question is not changing. [Here](https://github.com/francescocori/francesco-quizApp) is the github repository.
I did google a lot , I try to deploy it in both github and netlify but I can't manage to resolve this problem. Any help is appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested, and seems to be working fine!

Comment: This should be a comment, and not a separate answer.
You will be able to add comment after gaining some reputations.

Comment: yes I manage to fix it at the end! thanks!